# Percentage of groupby in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe that has columns 'team','home_or_away','result' to store the results ('W': win or 'L': loose) for teams 'X','Y','Z' in sporting events at home ('H') or away ('A'):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z', 'Z'],'home_or_away':['H', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'H', 'H', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'H'],'result':['W', 'W', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'L', 'L', 'L']})
```

I would like to generate the percentage of wins/losses per team, per event location ('A' or 'H')

I have  generated a dataframe with total counts of wins/losses per team and event location, with the following groupby code:

```
groupedDf =df.groupby(['team', 'home_or_away','result'])[['result']].count()
print(groupedDf)
```

with the following output:

```
                          result
team home_or_away result        
X    A            L            1
                  W            2
     H            W            1
Y    H            L            1
                  W            1
Z    A            L            1
     H            L            2
                  W            1
```

However, I would like to have an extra column with the percentage, like so:

```
                          result Perc
team home_or_away result        
X    A            L            1 33.33
                  W            2 66.66
     H            W            1 100
Y    H            L            1 50
                  W            1 50
Z    A            L            1 100
     H            L            2 66.66
                  W            1 33.33
```

How can I do this with pandas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.transform('sum')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the total per team/location:

```
groupedDf =df.groupby(['team', 'home_or_away','result'])[['result']].count()

total = (groupedDf.groupby(level=['team', 'home_or_away'])
         ['result'].transform('sum')
         )

groupedDf['Perc'] = groupedDf['result'] / total * 100
```

Output:

```
                          result        Perc
team home_or_away result                    
X    A            L            1   33.333333
                  W            2   66.666667
     H            W            1  100.000000
Y    H            L            1   50.000000
                  W            1   50.000000
Z    A            L            1  100.000000
     H            L            2   66.666667
                  W            1   33.333333
```

Answer (score 2):

Omit the grouping by `result`, and instead use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
out = df.groupby(['team', 'home_or_away']).value_counts(normalize=True)
```

out:

```
team  home_or_away  result
X     A             W         0.666667
                    L         0.333333
      H             W         1.000000
Y     H             L         0.500000
                    W         0.500000
Z     A             L         1.000000
      H             L         0.666667
                    W         0.333333
```

optionally multiply by 100.